# Custom Login Page in Qwik with Qwik-auth plugin

Tags: authentication, qwik

Qwik has a built in plugin for AuthJS called qwik auth (which as far as I am aware is undocumented). I’m not having any issue with it except that I want a custom login page (I want my form to authenticate the user instead of the default ugly form on /api/auth/signin) but I cannot figure out how to do this. Because there are no official docs, I’m not sure what to do. Do I need to make a POST request to some api built into Qwik? Is there a function I can call? If it helps, this is essentially what my code looks like: https://github.com/gilf/qwik-auth-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a traditional html form post as described at https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/pages#credentials-sign-in will work. You can get a csrf token from `/api/auth/csrf`.

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to make authentication happen immediately when a user goes to the webpage, have a look to `useBrowserVisibleTask$` (v0.19) aka [`useVisibleTask$`](https://qwik.builder.io/docs/components/lifecycle/#usevisibletask) in earlier versions.

I used this in the `root.tsx` file to check if the store had the session info, then proceeds to perform some authentication.

```js
useBrowserVisibleTask$(() => {
    if (store.auth.token == "") {
      refreshToken(store.auth);
      getUserInfo(store.auth, store.userSession)
    }
});
```

You can then utilise `useTask$` to track the changes to the store to perform re-rendering of the UI on successful authentication.

Comment: Thank you for the response but this is not what I’m trying to do: I have it such that the user is redirected to my custom login page when they go to authenticate, but I’m having trouble making the form. More specifically I don’t know what function to run when the the user submits the login form.

Answer (score 1):

Create a login page like this:

```
export default component$(() => {
  const loginAction = useAuthSignin();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        Welcome to Login <span class="lightning">⚡️</span>
      </h1>
      <div>
        <Form action={loginAction}>
          <div class="container">
            <input
              type="hidden"
              name="provider"
              value="credentials"
            />
            <input
                  type="text"
                  name="username"
            />
            <input
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
            />
            <div class="login">
              <button>Login</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});
```

I think that the login action provides the csrf token.

And in your auth.js config you can add a [custom login page](https://authjs.dev/reference/core#example-3)

```
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/signin',
    signOut: '/auth/signout',
    error: '/auth/error',
    verifyRequest: '/auth/verify-request',
    newUser: '/auth/new-user'
  }
```

The form action will call the [authorize credential provider function](https://github.com/gilf/qwik-auth-example/blob/main/src/routes/plugin%40auth.ts). This function have to return user data if the user exists

Maybe the best would be waiting that auth.js publish a new version with supports Qwik city and has the documentation

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward, you just need to add the custom page route to the serverAuth$ config and pass the Credentials through the `submit` method instead Form Action

serverAuth$ config `plugin@auth.ts`

```
...
callbacks:{...},
providers: {...},
pages: {
signIn: '/login', // your path
}
```

Now over at the `/login` route just call the `submit` method

```
signIn.submit({
    providerId: 'credentials', // Needs to be the credential provider not the credential name
    options: {
    email: authCred.email,
    password: authCred.password,
    callbackUrl: '/' // Redirect on Success
    }
})
```

Login Page example `login/index.tsx`

```
    export default componenet$(() => {

      export default component$(() => {
        const signIn = useAuthSignin();
        const authCred = useStore({
          email: '',
          password: ''
        });

        return ( <
          Form >
          <
          input name = 'email'
          onInput$ = {
            (e) => {
              authCred.email = (e.target as htmlInputElement).value
            }
          }
          /> <
          input name = 'password'
          onInput$ = {
            (e) => {
              authCred.password = (e.target as htmlInputElement).value
            }
          }
          /> <
          button type = 'submit'
          preventdefault:click 
          onClick$ = {
            $(
              signIn.submit({
                providerId: 'credentials', // Needs to be the credential provider not the credential name
                options: {
                  email: authCred.email,
                  password: authCred.password,
                  callbackUrl: '/' // Redirect on Success
                }
              })
            )
          } > < /button> <
          /Form>
        )
      })

    })
```